# SQL Query to calculate Total in hh:mm:ss Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a query wherein I am calculating time difference between following three actions

```
Production stop & Production start in hh:mm:ss format
Quality stop and quality start in hh:mm:ss format
shipping stop and shipping start in hh:mm:ss format
```

I want to some all three time differences which are in hh:mm:ss format. How cna I do that in SQL query?

MY query looks like following:

```
SELECT 

L.LOT_ID , 
L.LOT_ID_RECORD,
L.MAT_ID
L.QUANTITY

CONVERT(VARCHAR,LR.DT_PRODUCT_START,120) AS PRODUCTION_START,

ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,LR.DT_PRODUCT_ED,120) , 'NA' ) AS PRODUCTION_STOP,

convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, LR.DT_PRODUCT_START, LR.DT_PRODUCT_END)/3600)+':'+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, LR.DT_PRODUCT_START, LR.DT_PRODUCT_END)%3600/60)+':'+convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, LR.DT_PRODUCT_START, LR.DT_PRODUCT_END)%60)) as PRODUCTION_TIME,

CONVERT(VARCHAR,QC.QC_START,120) AS QC_START,

CONVERT(VARCHAR,QC.QC_CLOSE,120) AS QC_CLOSE,

convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, QC.QC_START ,QC.QC_CLOSE)/3600)+':'+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, QC.QC_START , QC.QC_CLOSE)%3600/60)+':'+convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, QC.QC_START,QC.QC_CLOSE)%60)) as QUALITY_TIME,

convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, S.SHIPPING_START, S.SHIPPING_CLOSE)/3600)+':'+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, S.SHIPPING_START, S.SHIPPING_CLOSE)%3600/60)+':'+convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, S.SHIPPING_START, S.SHIPPING_CLOSE)%60)) as SHIPPING_TIME

FROM XYZ
```

I want to sum `PRODUCTION_TIME , QUALITY_TIME and SHIPPING_TIME` and the result should be in `hh:mm:ss` format.

I'm not sure how to achieve that? Can you please help?

Regards !

Comment: Probably something like `CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, SUM(stuff), 0) AS TIME(0))`. EDIT: In this case, "stuff" would be your datediff(second, ...) values for each of the things you want to sum.

Comment: What happens if the result has more than 24 hours?

Comment: I need some of that 3 times. Does not matter if the result sum is more than 24 hours. Like 28:50:33

Comment: what is the (PRODUCTION_TIME , QUALITY_TIME and SHIPPING_TIME)'s data type in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Your posted query seems to be incomplete. IMHO, the best work around would be convert the three fields (to be sum up) to seconds then add those. Finally reconvert seconds to HH:MM:SS.